# How to run an Applescript at shutdown

Tags: shutdown, applescript

I am trying to track the occurrences and duration of power outages. I have my computer(Mac High Sierra) powered by a UPS and set to shutdown when there is an outage. I have an applescript that when run prints the time and date to a text file and am able to get that to run on start up. However, I am unable to get it to work when the computer shuts down. I have tried using launchd and logout hooks to no avail. How should I go about this?

Comment: Since you are already running a script at startup, just add the following example AppleScript code to your script to get the date and time the Mac last shutdown and process the result as wanted. `set lastShutdown to (do shell script "last | awk '/^shutdown/{print $3,$4,$5,$6; exit}'")`

Comment: Thank you @user3439894 That is exactly what I needed.